# Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 1 not found

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-dataflow

### Problem :

I am working with spring boot project and make as @Enabletask and tried to run with spring data flow.

I have up the spring dataflow server and in shell i tried to registered app and created task and when i run task i got the error.

By default it uses H2 database but i also tried with mysql also but facing same issue.

due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 1 not found,  application is not able to run and i am unable to see start time, end time and exit code on localhost:9393/

### Below are the solution i already tried,

1) Run dataflow server with mysql connection parameters.
--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb --spring.datasource.username=root --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

2) Run dataflow shell with mysql connection parameters.
--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb --spring.datasource.username=root --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

3) Execute task with mysql connection parameters.
--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb --spring.datasource.username=root --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

Already added mysql dependency in pom file.

Please find below code of main class

### Main class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.task.configuration.EnableTask;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTask
public class test {
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
        return new HelloWorldCommandLineRunner();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(test.class, args);
    }

    public static class HelloWorldCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

        @Override
        public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

### Pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!--    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version> -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>8.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a dependency on spring-boot-starter-jdbc? Also the mariadb driver.  I assume mysql server is running.  Check the log files for earlier errors.

Comment: Also you don’t need connection parameters for the shell.

Comment: I assume mysql server is running - YES

Do you need a dependency on spring-boot-starter-jdbc - NO

Also the mariadb driver - It is in springcloudserver jar , in my pom I have added mysqlconnector dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that I had reported on github. [https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/issues/446](http://issue)

The issue in my case was the spring boot and spring cloud versions. As I can see in your case as well, you are using spring boot 2.0.5 RELEASE whereas for spring cloud task starter you are using 1.2.3 RELEASE. This can cause a compatibility issue.

I would recommend you to try a newer release of that dependency which you can find here - 
[https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-task](http://maven%20dependency)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-task -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

1.x.x versions of spring cloud starter task are compatible with 1.x.x version of spring boot, similarly 2.x.x will be compatible with 2.x.x.